# `psycopg2` is installed in `Django Virtualenv` but still showing error

Tags: python, django

`PSYCOPG2` is installed in my virtualenv but still its showing error that no module named `psycopg2`

```
(blog_env) PS D:\django\blog_env\mysite> pip install psycopg2
Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in d:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages (2.7.5)
```

But still showing this Trace_Back Error when i run my project

```
C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe D:/Django/blog_env/mysite/populate.py
D:\Django\blog_env\mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 20, in <module>
    import psycopg2 as Database
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Django/blog_env/mysite/populate.py", line 5, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\base_user.py", line 47, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 114, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 315, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 205, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 202, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\postgresql\base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: No module named 'psycopg2'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: seems  you are running Django server outside the `blog_env`

Comment: @JerinPeterGeorge opss, solved it.. thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Your python version in your django server is `3.6`. But your env is for python 2.7.5.

`Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in d:\django\blog_env\lib\site-packages (2.7.5)`

`C:\Users\HP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe D:/Django/blog_env/mysite/populate.py`

If you are using python3, make env with python3 and install dependencies with `pip3`.